# React - How to loop and update values in object model?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have an object model pattern as below

```
   this.state = {
        data: {
            audi: {
                 engine: '2.5',
                 gearbox: 'auto',
                 fuel: 'petrol'
             },
             bmw: {
                 engine: '3.0',
                 gearbox: 'auto',
                 fuel: 'petrol'
             },
             merc: {
                 engine: '6.3',
                 gearbox: 'manual',
                 fuel: 'petrol'
             }
         }
    }
```

**My goal is to:**

1. Loop through the data and render
2. Map value changes in the HTML to
   the corresponding keys in the this.state.data object

*I haven't used an Array, as it has to look like above object pattern when posting it.*

At the moment here is how I am trying to do this:

```
//To render
Object.entries(this.state.data).map((x,index) =>
    <p>x.key</p> //Trying to reach 'audi' with x.key

    // Render each KPV in object
    {x.key}: <input key={index} onChange={this.handleChange} value={x.value}/>
)
```

Then to update the corresponding values in the same state model:

```
// To update the state model with changed values
setData = (key, val) => {
    this.setState(state => ({
        data: {
            ...state.data,
            obj: { [key]: val },
            //Don't know how to map to state properly!
        }
    }));
};

// Handle input change
handleChange = key => e => {
    this.setData(key, e.target.value);
};
```

Please could anyone advise me on this approach, many thanks :)

Comment: What issue you are facing actually?

Comment: How exactly you are expecting it, share sample if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to get the rendering right, which means looping over all the keys (car makers) and then all the property/value pairs. You can use destructuring arrays to make this easier

```
Object.entries(someObject).map( ([key,value]) => .... )
```

Heres rendering:

```
render() {
    return Object.entries(this.state.data).map(([maker, props]) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>{maker}</h2>
          {Object.entries(props).map(([key, value], index) => {
            return (
              <div>
                {key}:{" "}
                <input
                  key={index}
                  onChange={this.handleChange(maker, key)}
                  defaultValue={value}
                />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
```

You'll note I changed your `handleChange` method to pass the car maker and the property being edited - this can be passed to `setData` :

```
// To update the state model with changed values
  setData = (maker, key, val) => {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      data: {
        ...state.data,
        [maker]: {
          ...state.data[maker],
          [key]: val
        }
        //Don't know how to map to state properly! Now you do!
      }
    }));
  };

  // Handle input change
  handleChange = (maker, key) => (e) => {
    this.setData(maker, key, e.target.value);
  };
```

Live working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-dw9sg

Comment: Thanks @Jamiec this helped me loads

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing key and event object from the input callback in the first place, your code should be like,

The display logic looks wrong to me,

```js
Object.entries(this.state.data).map((x, index) =>
    /* 
     here x is an array and it looks like 
     ["audi", {engine: '2.5', gearbox: 'auto', fuel: 'petrol}
    */
     // You need to access the data in the second index
     // if you want to print each value of the object
    <p>x[1].engine</p>
    <p>x[1].gearbox</p>
    <p>x[1].fuel</p> 

    // Render each KPV in object
    {x[0]}: <input key={index} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(x[0], e)} value={x[1].engine}/>
)
```

and `handleChange` callback should look like, don't curry them.

```js
handleChange = (key, e) => {
    this.setData(key, e.target.value);
};
```

And I would suggest using a utility like castArray from lodash, https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#castArray to convert the object to an array so that you can easily work with it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      data: {
        audi: { model: "A7", transmission: "AT" },
        merc: { model: "GLA", transmission: "MT" },
        bmw: { model: "M3", transmission: "AT" },
      },
    }
  }
  update(make, detail, value) {
    let data = this.state.data
    data[make][detail] = value
    console.log(`Updating ${make} ${detail} with ${value}`)
    this.setState({ data: data })
  }
  handleChange(make, detail) {
    return e => { this.update(make, detail, e.target.value) }
  }
  renderDetails(details) {
    return details.map(d => (<div><span>{d.key}:</span> <input value={d.model} onChange={this.handleChange(d.key, "model")} /> <input value={d.transmission} onChange={this.handleChange(d.key, "transmission")} /></div>))
  }
  render() {
    const details = Object.entries(this.state.data).map(d => ({ key: d[0], ...d[1] }))
    return <div>{this.renderDetails(details)}</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render((<App />), document.getElementById("app"))
```

```css
body { font-family: monospace; }
span { display: block; font-weight: bold; }
input { width: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```